# Hard drive format / Windows reinstall

Tags: windows-10, formatting, product-key

I have a new windows 10 laptop and wish  to format the hard drive. Is it possible to find the product key to reinstall the windows onto a different hard drive?

Comment: You don’t need the product key to reinstall Windows 10.  Windows 10 will automatically activate.  I suggest just using the Windows 10 Reset will avoid in the hassle of having to boot into an installation environment and you get exactly the same results

Answer (score 0):

If it is OEM version(system is pre-installed on hardware and has been activated), in general, activation information is bound to hardware(such as motherboard) and it is not transferable. If your laptop is OEM version, please contact your laptop manufacturer/provider and confirm with them about the system re-installation and re-activation.

If it is not OEM version, please reference article - **Find your Windows product key**:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10749/windows-product-key